# Error with MSVCP120.DLL?

Tags: c++, dll, installation

My friend is trying to make a install shield for a game he made. And I'm getting an error all the time that we can't figure out why pops up... It says:

> .../GameFolder/MSVCP120.DLL is either not design to run on Windows or
>   is damaged.

What is this error caused by? We wasn't able to find much on google.

I'm running Windows 7, 64-bit

Comment: I would just install the microsoft redistributable from VS2013 instead of copying dlls.

Answer (score 0):

Install Microsoft redistributable 2013 from:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784